# Detect Anchor tag in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree

My anchor tag is not working

here is my code :

```
   $('.tree div').click(function(){
                    var o = $(this);
                    o.children('div').slideToggle();
                    o.filter(".parent").toggleClass("expand");
                    return false;

                });
```

my html code is :

```
 <div class="tree">
            <div class="parent">
                Parent
                <div class="parent">
                    Parent 1
                    <div>
                        <a href="http://google.com">Childe 2.1</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Childe 2.2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="parent">
                    Parent 2 
                    <div>
                        one 3.1
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        one 3.2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parent">
                Parent
                <div class="parent">
                    parent 1
                    <div>
                        Childe 2.1
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Childe 2.2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="parent">
                    parent 2
                    <div>
                        Childe 2.1
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Childe 2.2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but when i click on Childe 2.1 it doesn't  open google.com

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: if you click a link it will take you where it points to.

Comment: It works if you remove return false;

Comment: I copy pasted this in for myself and unlike what you say it doesn't go to google

Comment: I think "does" is supposed to be "doesn't" (typo!)

Comment: yup it works after deleting return false;  but it doesn't expand properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. The `e.stopPropagation()` is what I added.

```
$('.tree div').click(function(e){
                var o = $(this);
                o.children('div').slideToggle();
                o.filter(".parent").toggleClass("expand");
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
```

- Note I also added `e` as an argument to the function `function(e)`.
- [Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

I take it from...

> but when i click on Childe 2.1 it does open google.com

... You want to prevent the link behaviour?

In which case you need the following code:

```
$(".tree A").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If this is not what you are asking, please expand your OP to include more details about your problem, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: when i click on parent menu it displays child menus.

Comment: Yes... that's what your code is doing? You've still not detailed what the problem is here.